# Найти в каждом нечетном столбце матрицы элемент с максимальным по модулю значением и позицию этого элемента

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Нужно найти в каждом нечетном столбце матрицы элемент с максимальным по модулю значением и позицию этого элемента. Матрица сделана,а вот сам алгоритм булеберду выводит.   Как нужно поправить,чтобы все нормально работало?

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m, n, i, j, max;
    cin >> m >> n;
    int mass[n][m];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            mass[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            //cout << mass[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        //cout << "\n";
    }

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (j % 2 != 0)
            max = mass[0][j];
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (mass[i][j] > max)
                max = mass[i][j];
        cout << max;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Фигурные скобки после `if (j%2!=0)` забыли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем-то, у меня не ответ - ответ вам дали; так, тянет на комментарий, но в него невозможно воткнуть отформатированный исходник.

Вот смотрите - стоит просто отформатировать его (что делает практически любой нормальный редактор) - и вы получите, например:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m, n, i, j,max;
    cin >> m >> n;
    int mass[n][m];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            mass[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            //cout << mass[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        //cout << "\n";
    }

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if (j%2!=0)
            max = mass [0][j];
        for (i=1; i<n; i++)
            if (mass[i][j] > max)
                max = mass [i][j];
        cout << max;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

И мгновенно, пройти одним беглым взглядом - и вы натыкаетесь на не тот уровень вложенности, где вам указал @HolyBlackCat.

Программы пишутся не для компиляторов, а для людей. Неаккуратное форматирование, отсутствие комментариев и т.п. стилевые нарушения - это грабли, на которых вы танцуете.

И еще - раз уж это C++, то учтите, что в нем вот такое

```
    cin >> m >> n;
    int mass[n][m];
```

не работает. Не поддерживает язык С++ такие фокусы. То, что GCC такое пропустит, говорит только о том, что это - расширение GCC :)